# Windows 7 64bit - Sleep\resume c# code

Tags: c#, windows, sleep, resume

I need to create a program in c# code that will sleep my machine for X mins and then resume from sleep mode. I have written a program to sleep\hibernate my machine using PowerState.Suspend which I run on one thread and then I set a timer for x mins after which I run System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(); to resume from sleep. 
I have been searching all over but alas, I am still not happy.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can resume my laptop from a sleep state in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this method:

http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/6/18/wake-up-from-sleep-createwaitabletimer-in-c.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I have it working now. Used code from both resources. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use P/invoke to call call the `CreateWaitableTimer` and `SetWaitableTimer` functions.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this example](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/6/18/wake-up-from-sleep-createwaitabletimer-in-c.html) of calling the functions from C#.